# Is it possible to deploy multiple WKS custom models in Watson Natural Language Understanding?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

1) If I use Watson Knowledge Studio to create a custom model that deployed to Watson Natural Language understanding, is the model additive to the existing 'out of the box' model used by Watson NLU?  In other words, will NLU continue to identify 'company' and 'person' entities and relations, available from NLU?  2)  Is it possible to deploy more than one custom model defined for separate domains?  @German Attanasio, @Hiroaki Komine, saw that you answered a few related questions.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: PLEASE STOP SHOUTING ALSO THOSE PEOPLE YOU'RE TRYING TO PING AREN'T GOING TO GET NOTIFIED

Answer (score 1):

1) Deploying WKS custom model would not replace the default model provided by NLU. You have to specify the model ID to use the WKS custom model. Otherwise, the default model is used. 2) NLU Free plan allows you to deploy single custom model. But NLU paid plan allows you to deploy multiple models.

I also answered at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/392086/does-a-custom-model-deployed-from-wks-to-watson-na.html#answer-392116

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry for shouting :) in the ask.  To clarify your answer to 1), if I specify a model ID for the custom model and deploy in NLU, I will see entities tagged by both the out of box NLU model and my custom model.  is that correct?  2) . How many custom models can be deployed in the paid NLU plan that allow multiple models?  Is there any advice on deploying multiple models?  I'm interested in using multiple models, each to handle a  different knowledge domain.  Thanks.

Comment: For (1), if you have specified your custom model ID, the entities and relations are extracted by the specified custom model. It can not extract with the default mode.
For (2), there is no limitation specified for Standard instance n Bluemix catalog. But deployed model will be charged.
https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/natural-language-understanding?env_id=ibm:yp:au-syd

Comment: Thank you Komine-San, for clarification.  The reason for my question is the desire to improve the existing NLU model with additional dictionary terms or  rules without having to start a model from scratch.  Are there additional assets available that i use in WKS to help bootstrap a new model?   I did the tutorial at https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/wks/tutorials.html#wks_tutintro and used the 'KLUE' type system and built a few dictionaries that was helpful.  Any suggestions on additional assets?

Comment: Right now, we do not have any exiting Corpus that can be re-used for additional WKS model deployment. We are evaluating how we can help WKS annotator to create extended Corpus from existing template rather than creating from scratch. This plan is still in evaluation and not happen yet.

Answer (score 0):

Watson Discovery supports multiple custom models in the Advanced or Premium plans: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/discovery?topic=discovery-integrating-with-wks#integrate-multiplecustom

I think the same method of configuration can be used for Watson Natural Language understanding in the Standard or Premium plans.